# RabbitMQ: How to prevent QueueDeclare to automatically generate a new Queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, message-queue

With RabbitMQ I am doing something similar to this:

```
channel.QueueDeclare(QueueName, true, false, false, null);
```

By default RabbitMQ creates a new queue if none of the existing matches the name provided. I would like to have an exception thrown instead.
Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to implement? Have you tried using a Passive declare?

Comment: I just want to use a queue without declaring it if missing. I will investigate about the Passive declare. Thank you

Comment: If the queue is missing, then you have to declare it, there's no way around it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can bind to existing queue without declaring a new one.

```cs
try
{
    channel.QueueBind(queueName, exchange, routingKey);
}
catch (RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException ex)
{
    // Queue not found
}
```

An example of the exception thrown if the queue you're trying to bind does not exist:

> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=404, text="NOT_FOUND - no queue 'TestQueue' in vhost '/'", classId=50, methodId=20, cause=

Answer (score 10):

Passive declarations are made for this. Use [`IModel.QueueDeclarePassive()`](https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/api/RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.html#RabbitMQ_Client_IModel_QueueDeclarePassive_System_String_):

```cs
model.QueueDeclarePassive("queue-name");
```

This does nothing if the queue already exists, and raises an exception otherwise.

Comment: if the queue exists it will raise an exception, than it's needed to use try catch. `            try{
                ch.queueDeclarePassive​(queue);
            } catch (java.io.IOException ex){

            }`